# EXCEL VBA ERROR 424

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to copy some cells in vba based on their column, from an excel file chosen by the user (req), to another fixed file (rfqq). below is my code which brings error 424, object required.
could anyone help?.I am a newbie and expect a very simple answer to this!

```
Sub rfqo()

Dim rfq As Workbook
Dim req as variant
Dim rowcount, rfqc, reqab, i As Integer
req = Application.GetOpenFilename
If req = False Then
MsgBox "No file specified.", vbExclamation, "Duh!!!"
    Exit Sub
Else
Workbooks.Open Filename:=req
    End If
      rowcount = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
Set rfq = Workbooks.Open("c:\users\mostafa\desktop\rfqq.xlsx")
For i = 1 To rowcount + 12
rfqc = 12 + i
reqab = 2 + i
rfq.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C12:C" & rfqc).Value = _
req.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("AB2:AB" & reqab).Value
rfq.Sheets("sheet1").Range("e12:e" & rfqc).Value = _
req.Sheets("sheet1").Range("ac2:ac" & reqab).Value
rfq.Sheets("sheet1").Range("f12:f" & rfqc).Value = _ 
req.Sheets("sheet1").Range("af2:af" & reqab).Value
rfq.Sheets("sheet1").Range("e12:e" & rfqc).Value = _
req.Sheets("sheet1").Range("ac2:ac" & reqab).Value
rfq.Sheets("sheet1").Range("g12:g" & rfqc).Value = __
req.Sheets("sheet1").Range("ag2:ag" & reqab).Value
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: What line throws the error?

Comment: `req` is the *name* of a workbook, not a workbook object.

Comment: @sam This one: rfq.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C12:C" & rfqc).Value = _
req.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("AB2:AB" & reqab).Value

Comment: @mostafa danaiefar: are you sure that `req` is a workbook object - it looks like it would be a string so when you try to call a range on it you are getting the error

Comment: as Rory says, you need to define req as a workbook, something like `set req=workbooks.open filename:= name`

Comment: There you have it, `req` is a string (path to the selected file), not a workbook.

Comment: @philip req is the name i gave to the workbook I want to open and get data from, how should i define it?

Comment: @sam changed req to string , this time I get error "invalid qualifier"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to define the variable `req` as a workbook object, and use a different string for the name of the workbook you want to open.

so change your code as below:

```
Dim rfq As Workbook, req as Workbook '~~>Change 'req' to Workbook type
Dim vBookName as variant '~~>Add new variant to capture the name
Dim rowcount As Integer, rfqc As Integer, reqab As Integer, i As Integer
'~~>without 'As Integer' statements, all but the last one of these was a variant

vBookName = Application.GetOpenFilename '~~>replace 'req' w 'vBookName' in this section
If vBookName = False Then
MsgBox "No file specified.", vbExclamation, "Duh!!!"
    Exit Sub
Else
    Set req = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=vBookName) '~~> Use 'Set' as 'req' is an object
End If

rowcount = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
Set rfq = Workbooks.Open("c:\users\mostafa\desktop\rfqq.xlsx")
```

Comment: the line "  set req =Workbooks.Open Filename:=vBookName " brings syntax error,also tried multiple other options, yet no chance

Comment: Should be `Set req = Workbooks.Open(FileName:=vBookName)`

Comment: @mostafadanaiefar if you're still getting an errror, please indicate what the error message says.

Comment: thanks for your changes and fixes David - I actually wrote it off the top of my head as a quick answer and it obviously needed some improvements!